# How do I make these fold expressions work?

Tags: c++, templates, fold-expression

I'm not understanding why this is not working:

```
template <typename ... Types>
void func()
{

    (std::cout << typeid(Types).name(), ...) ; // Syntax error, unexpected token '...', expected 'expression'
    (static_assert(std::is_integral_v<Types>, "Type must be integral type"), ...); // Syntax error: unexpected token 'static_assert', expected 'expression'
}
int main()
{
    func<int, short>();

}
```

My understanding is that the compiler should basically go:

```
(static_assert(std::is_integral_v<Types>, "Error message"), ...)
```

The comma is an operator and what's before the operator should get repeated for each type in the parameter pack. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 3):

Fold expressions can't contain (unparenthesized) operators with precedence lower than that of a cast.

So either add parentheses: `((std::cout << typeid(Types).name()), ...);`

Or fold over `<<` instead: `(std::cout << ... << typeid(Types).name());`

---

As for `static_assert`, it's a declaration rather than an expression, so you can't fold it.

Use one big `static_assert`, with a `&&`-fold expression:

```
static_assert((std::is_integral_v<Types> && ...), "Type must be integral type")
```

Answer (score 2):

Operator `<<` requires `...` to be placed inbetween operators. `static_assert` is not an expression and therefore fold expression won't help. The workaround is to create a dedicated check function with a single `static_assert` and invoke this function folding built-in operator `,` invocations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename x_Type>
constexpr void is_integral_check(void) noexcept
{
    static_assert(::std::is_integral_v<x_Type>, "Type must be an integral type.");
    return;
}

template<typename ... x_Types>
void func()
{
    (::std::cout << ... << typeid(x_Types).name());
    (is_integral_check<x_Types>(), ...);
}

int main()
{
    func<int, short>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5G4xxc15s

Answer (score 1):

You first syntax error my be the result of not using C++17 as fold expression were introduced there.
I tried to compile your code with C++14 and got the same syntax error.

```
(std::cout << typeid(Types).name(), ...);  // needs C++17, Syntax error with C++14
```

The second one can be rewritten like this:

```
static_assert((std::is_integral_v<Types> && ...), "Type must be integral type");
```